How to enable NetBIOS over TCP/IP on an ethernet of a Domain Controller?
I recently did some cable management (including ethernet). After I was done, I found that none of my Synology NAS units weren't able to reconnect to the Active Directory on my domain server. To be exact, they did intermittently reconnect, but disconnect roughly every other time I checked it. Fiddling with the domain setting on the NAS made no difference.
Tracing back, the only thing that was different is that I installed the recent server updates before shutting it down for cable management:

2024-11 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based Systems (KB5046612)
Security Update for SQL Server 2017 RTM GDR (KB5046857)
2024-09 Servicing Stack Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based Systems (KB5043124)

I tried reverting back by uninstalling the updates, but it makes no difference. After troubleshooting for the past few days, I noticed something I haven't before. The ethernet port on the Domain Controller has NetBIOS over TCP/IP disabled. Research says that NetBIOS is required for SMB to work, which makes sense why the Synology NAS units can't properly reconnect if they can't get SMB to work reliably. (Note that I have disabled SMB 1.0 long ago for security and performance reason, and it did work with no issue when SMB 1.0 was disabled.)
However, I can't seem to figure how to get NetBIOS over TCP/IP enabled. Is it not possible for ethernet port, vEthernet (Virtual Switch)?
What I have tried:

Changing the setting in the WINS tab of IPv4 setting from Default to Enable NetBIOS over TCP/IP with IPv6 disabled.
Edit the registry in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters for all the interfaces I saw for the key value NetbiosOptions from 0 to 1.

Thinking that it might be a Windows bug, I installed the latest update, but it is still disabled:
2024-12 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based Systems (KB5048671)

NetBIOS is required for SMB. No it is not.

Oh, I thought it was. After further reading, SMB on Windows can run directly over TCP/IP without the need for NetBIOS. But I am guessing that SMB version in Synology relies on NetBIOS API as explained here. Thus, I am still back to the original question: how to enable NetBIOS over TCP/IP?

No, absolutely not. NetBIOS has not been needed for 25 years. It was replaced by DNS. It is also a critical security risk. SMB works 100% without NetBIOS.

Really? In that case, I am stumped why both Synology suddenly stops communicate with the domain controller recently.

Okay, so Synology does have nmbd running in the background. I disabled it hoping that it would allow it to reconnect to the domain controller more stably by fully relying on DNS, but it is still intermittently connected. I am back to the drawing board.

I would check cabling, and run a packet capture to see if any packets are actually reaching the domain controller.

Greg might be confusing "NetBIOS API" in general with "NetBIOS Name Service" in particular – there are other components to NetBIOS that have nothing to do with DNS – but generally it's true that neither Active Directory nor modern SMB rely on any NetBIOS features; certainly not the Name Service, and not the Session Service (which SMBv1 used but later versions do not). Pre-AD domain joins (NT4 domains) were "NetBIOS domains" in a sense, and it's possible that Synology runs an ancient Samba3 that can only join an NT4 domain (or an AD domain through NT4 compatibility), but I hope it doesn't..

To provide more detail about NetBIOS (2024 holiday edition), many organizations have scripts that run during startup to assure that NetBIOS is disabled due to it is a critical security risk. The script typically runs: wmic nicconfig where TcpipNetbiosOptions!=2 call SetTcpipNetbios 2 . https://proxyadvices.wordpress.com/2015/06/04/how-to-automate-a-change-of-netbios-settings-in-properties-of-a-network-connection-in-windows/

I see no packet loss on the switch end, so I installed Wireshark on the domain controller and discovered that both Synology NAS units are consistently broadcasting NBNS querying for the domain name even though I stopped nmbd service and they are able to query for it successfully via DNS. Also, there are no reply back from the domain controller on requests by NAS to initiate TCP communication on port 139 and 445 even though the domain controller is listening at port 445. Port 139 is closed and is blocked by firewall. Does that mean NetBIOS over TCP/IP is required?

I finally located the source of the problem. It was the

binding issue where the process or 'port' can't bind to the actual NIC
itself

as stated by Gostega here.
Even though the domain controller was showing via netstat -an command that it is listening at port 445, it is not working as expected. I believe that this problem has occurred for quite some times, but I didn't have any issue with it since I didn't use SMB on the server much and it was able to fallback to NetBIOS over TCP/IP till it was disabled recently.
I recalled fixing Synology Active Directory issue in the past now by removing and adding back the virtual ethernet adapter. Since I don't remember how I did that last time, I uninstalled and reinstalled Hyper-V server instead; thereby, it got rid of the problematic virtual ethernet adapter and recreated a working one. While this is not the best solution, it is a solution that I used.
Afterward, I did further testing if I can disable NetBIOS over TCP/IP since it is security risk. And it continues to work with no issue.
